# How to use iMonkey in an iOS app

Tags: javascript, objective-c, ios

[iMonkey](https://github.com/couchbaselabs/iMonkey) looks like an interesting way of embedding a JS runtime in an iOS app, but I can't find any examples on how to actually run some JS code.

I can build/link the lib, include the jsapi.h header (from the src directory), but it trips over various linker errors ('undefined symbol for architecture...') when I try some example code from spider monkey (see below). To be clear, this is pretty much a copy-paste from a Mac related posting on another site, I am not at all sure if this is how it should be done. I am sure I have the right static library (universal) for my architecture (simulator).

Anyone knows how to do this?

```
#include "jsapi.h"

.....

JSRuntime *rt;
JSContext *cx;
JSObject  *global;

/* Create a JS runtime. */
rt = JS_NewRuntime(8L * 1024L * 1024L);

/* Create a context. */
cx = JS_NewContext(rt, 8192);
JS_SetOptions(cx, JSOPTION_VAROBJFIX);

/* Create the global object. */
global = JS_NewObject(cx, &global_class, NULL, NULL);

/* Populate the global object with the standard globals,
 like Object and Array. */
if (!JS_InitStandardClasses(cx, global))
    @throw [[NSException alloc]initWithName:@"JSerror" reason:@"jserrpr" userInfo:nil];

/* Cleanup. */
JS_DestroyContext(cx);
JS_DestroyRuntime(rt);
JS_ShutDown();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example loosely based off the examples found in the original spider monkey.

http://egachine.berlios.de/embedding-sm-best-practice/embedding-sm-best-practice.html

I modified so it works with multi threading (which is already enabled by iMonkey).

https://developer.mozilla.org/En/SpiderMonkey/Internals/Thread_Safety

```
//
//  JSEngine.mm
//  POC_JS
//
//  Created by Quoc Le on 7/12/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import "JSEngine.h"

/* get SpiderMonkey API declarations */
#include <jsapi.h>
/* EXIT_FAILURE and EXIT_SUCCESS */
#include <stdlib.h>  
/* strlen */
#include <string.h>


@implementation JSEngine

+ (int) run
{
    /* pointer to our runtime object */
    JSRuntime *runtime=NULL;
    /* pointer to our context */
    JSContext *context=NULL;
    /* pointer to our global JavaScript object */
    JSObject  *global=NULL;

    /* script to run (should return 100) */
    char *script="var x=10;x*x;";
    /* JavaScript value to store the result of the script */
    jsval rval;

    /* create new runtime, new context, global object */
    if (    (!(runtime = JS_NewRuntime (1024L*1024L)))
        || (!(context = JS_NewContext (runtime, 8192)))
        ) return EXIT_FAILURE;

    JS_SetContextThread(context);
    JS_BeginRequest(context);

    //        || (!(global  = JS_NewObject  (context, NULL, NULL, NULL)))

    global  = JS_NewObject  (context, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    /* set global object of context and initialize standard ECMAScript
     objects (Math, Date, ...) within this global object scope */
    if (!JS_InitStandardClasses(context, global)) return EXIT_FAILURE;

    /* now we are ready to run our script */
    if (!JS_EvaluateScript(context, global,script, strlen(script),
                           "script", 1, &rval))
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    /* check if the result is really 100 */
    NSLog(@"RSVAL %d", JSVAL_TO_INT(rval));
    if (!(JSVAL_IS_INT(rval)&&(JSVAL_TO_INT(rval)==100)))
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    JS_EndRequest(context);
    JS_ClearContextThread(context);

    /* clean up */
    //JS_DestroyContext(context);
    //JS_DestroyRuntime(runtime);
    //JS_ShutDown();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with linker. just add libstdc++6 to your project to avoid this problem